# Randomize numbers in VB.NET without using a range i.e. Min and Max

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, random

I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction please? Say I am pulling the following table, I would then like to select an ID randomly. I understand how to select a random number using a Randomize() call followed by the relevant syntax but I want to pre-define the range.

i.e. Table Data

### ID        | Name

4345        Mike

3456        Lee

4567        John

There will be many more names but for this example you could use 3 or 4 etc..

Please help I'm starting to itch :o|

Comment: How do you want to predefine the range, alphabetical?

Answer (score 2):

Just to make sure I understand what you want:

Given a table, you want to randomly select one of the ID values from that table.

If so, this should do it:

```
Dim rand As New Random()
Dim record As Integer = rand.[Next](0, myDataTable.Rows.Count)
Dim randomID As Integer = CInt(myDataTable.Rows(record)("ID"))
```

We have all the information we need to randomly select a *row*, and by extension randomly select one of the ID values in the table.

Answer (score 0):

In old Vb you would do

```
    Dim i as integer 

   i = (Rnd * (maxval-minval)) + minval
```

Since rnd returns a random number between 0 and 1 you would scale the number to the right range.